# Remove duplicated rows based on 2 columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I am new in R. I have this data frame:

```
TimeStamp  IndexA IndexB Value
12:00:01    1      NA    Windows
12:00:05    1      NA    Windows
12:00:13    1      NA    Windows
12:00:48    NA     1     Macintosh
12:01:30    NA     1     Macintosh
12:01:45    NA     1     Macintosh
12:02:01    2      NA    Windows
12:02:13    2      NA    Windows
```

And I want to remove duplicated rows based on columns `IndexA` and `Value` or `IndexB` and `Value`. So, in the end the data frame should be seen like this:

```
TimeStamp  IndexA IndexB Value
12:00:01    1      NA    Windows
12:00:48    NA     1     Macintosh
12:02:01    2      NA    Windows
```

How can I manage this ?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.. Also, seems like possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742446/duplicates-in-multiple-columns

Comment: @Tanu I am sure there have been similar questions already been asked on SO but the Q you have linked to is not a duplicate, IMHO. In the linked Q *all* rows containing duplicate entries are to be removed whereas here the first entry is to be kept.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe for pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, the `unique()` function from the `data.table` package can be used as well:

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df), by = "IndexA")
```

> ```
>    TimeStamp IndexA IndexB     Value
> 1:  12:00:01      1     NA   Windows
> 2:  12:00:48     NA      1 Macintosh
> 3:  12:02:01      2     NA   Windows
> ```

This is looking for unique values only in `IndexA` which is equivalent to [Tito Sanz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847337/3817004). Obviously, this approach returns the expected result for the given sample data set but checking only *one* column for duplicate entries is oversimplifying IMHO and may fail with production data.

Or, looking for unique combinations of the values in *three* columns (which is equivalent to [www's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847379/3817004)):

```
unique(setDT(df), by = 2:4) # very terse
unique(setDT(df), by = c("IndexA", "IndexB", "Value")) # explicitely named cols
```

> ```
>    TimeStamp IndexA IndexB     Value
> 1:  12:00:01      1     NA   Windows
> 2:  12:00:48     NA      1 Macintosh
> 3:  12:02:01      2     NA   Windows
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  "TimeStamp  IndexA IndexB Value
12:00:01    1      NA    Windows
12:00:05    1      NA    Windows
12:00:13    1      NA    Windows
12:00:48    NA     1     Macintosh
12:01:30    NA     1     Macintosh
12:01:45    NA     1     Macintosh
12:02:01    2      NA    Windows
12:02:13    2      NA    Windows")
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution using `dplyr`. We can use the `distinct` function. `-TimeStamp` is to specify this column is excluded when considering duplication. `.keep_all = TRUE` means to keep all the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  distinct(-TimeStamp, .keep_all = TRUE)
dt2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   TimeStamp IndexA IndexB     Value
#       <chr>  <int>  <int>     <chr>
# 1  12:00:01      1     NA   Windows
# 2  12:00:48     NA      1 Macintosh
# 3  12:02:01      2     NA   Windows
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "TimeStamp  IndexA IndexB Value
12:00:01    1      NA    Windows
                 12:00:05    1      NA    Windows
                 12:00:13    1      NA    Windows
                 12:00:48    NA     1     Macintosh
                 12:01:30    NA     1     Macintosh
                 12:01:45    NA     1     Macintosh
                 12:02:01    2      NA    Windows
                 12:02:13    2      NA    Windows",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` function in `tidyverse` package.

```
foo %>% 
  distinct(IndexA, .keep_all = T)
```

Here is the result:

```
  TimeStamp IndexA IndexB     Value
1  12:00:01      1     NA   Windows
2  12:00:48     NA      1 Macintosh
3  12:02:01      2     NA   Windows
```